# Json paser output with quotes

Tags: json

I need it to output with quotes i've tried a few different ways with no luck this needs to output like this bind = "0.0.0.0:25577" but it just out puts like this 
bind = 0.0.0.0:25577

```
{
    "velocity.toml": {
        "parser": "toml",
        "find": {
            "bind": "{{server.build.default.ip}}:{{server.build.default.port}}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you build your json?

Comment: i honestly dont know cause its a panel praising  json i know nothing to very little about json

Comment: the double quotes are syntax elements of json, the does not belong to the values.

Comment: could you give me a run down on that @jens